# Adding a border to a flash.display.Loader

Tags: actionscript-3, image, adobe, loader, blackberry-playbook

I'm developing an ActionScript 3 app for Blackberry PlayBook.

I'm loading an image with flash.display.Loader.

I want to show that image with a 5px black border.

How can I do that?

Comment: as a side are you going to be compiling the code through the terminal? I'm having problem in that front

Comment: @Saad: I'm using Flash Builder Burrito. I don't know if this is what you asking for. I'm also using Playbook emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's one approach. First you place the loader inside a "background" object at 5 px. from the top left.

```
background = new Sprite();
addChild(background);

loader = new Loader();

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
    loaderCompleteHandler);

loader.load(new URLRequest(url));

background.addChild(loader);

// place loader 5 px. from top left
loader.x = 5;
loader.y = 5;
```

And then you draw the background based on the dimensions of the image (add 10 px.).

```
private function loaderCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var w:Number = loader.contentLoaderInfo.width;
    var h:Number = loader.contentLoaderInfo.height;

    var g:Graphics = background.graphics;

    g.clear();

    // draw background
    g.beginFill(0x000000);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, w + 10, h + 10);
    g.endFill();
}
```

Instead of adding the loader to the background Sprite object, you can also just keep it in its existing parent container and just add the background Sprite to that container itself, but behind the loader. (In that case you can use Shape instead of Sprite for the background)

You could also just draw a border around the loader object in its existing parent container. See flash.display.Graphics API.

Answer (score 0):

get the width and height of the image then draw a bg behind  (+x width +y height) the image. if you're adding child into a mc you can use the .graphic from the flash.display library or just use bitmapdata and add to a bitmap, the former is easier.

Comment: @VansFannel mj. has a good example of this on the post below, but I should warn you that the graphics class seems to be cpu intensive. When I was building  graphing program using the draw line and draw boxes was very intensive; i ended up using bitmapData. I was however simulating movement in mealtime (1s update) so if you have a lot of images being added simultaneously you may run into issues